# Track time taken to fix a comment after raising code review request in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to track the time taken to fix a review comment (or discussion) after raising a code review request in TFS 2017. This is because we want to track the metrics such as code quality, rework effort, etc.

Note: I'm pretty new to TFS code review stuff so please bear with me if my question sounds quite dumb.

Answer (score 0):

You could see all the date information from code review request workitem. Using a query to find the corresponding code review request workitem. All the date information could be see that workitem under the **System Info** tab.

This could be achieved by using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Discussion.Client in TFS Client SDK. Following is the code sample to get who and when put the comment by  [DiscussionThread class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.discussionthread.aspx):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
            var comments = new List<CodeReviewComment>();
            int workItemId = 52;
            var uri = new Uri("http://servername:8080/tfs/MttCollection");
            var service = new TeamFoundationDiscussionService();

            service.Initialize(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri));
            IDiscussionManager discussionManager = service.CreateDiscussionManager();


            var result = discussionManager.BeginQueryByCodeReviewRequest(workItemId, QueryStoreOptions.ServerOnly, CallCompletedCallback, null);
            var output = discussionManager.EndQueryByCodeReviewRequest(result);

            foreach (DiscussionThread thread in output)
            {
                if (thread.RootComment != null)
                {                    
                    Console.WriteLine(thread.PublishedDate + thread.RootComment.Author.DisplayName);                   
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();           
 }



 static void CallCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
 {
            // Handle error conditions here
 }
```